# Launch activity after x minutes

Tags: android

I want to launch an activity after some selected time(10mins, 15min, 20mins, 30min, 45min, 60mins) and also if the app is closed and the phone is locked. i want this activity to popup with a music being played.

Comment: http://www.androidhive.info/2013/07/how-to-implement-android-splash-screen-2/ refer this link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this code:

```
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                Intent intent = new Intent(SplashScreen.this, MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        }, SPLASH_TIME_OUT); // SPLASH_TIME_OUT - your time in  miliseconds
```

Comment: The activity i want to create is for a alarm and not for splash screen and it should be launched from a service hence i cannot use SplashScreen.this in the toast as mentioned